# Visual Studio 2012 c++ ATL/COM

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I can't find any books on COM+/ATL development with Visual Studio 2012 c++. What are the best resource for learning ATL? Will older books written from 2000-2003 still apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old books are still in good standing, over last years ATL changes are mostly bugfixes and minor improvements (easy to see if one, for instance, compares \VC\atlmfc\include\atl*.* files of 2008, 2010 and 2012 Visual Studio).

Comment: Do you recommend a good book?

Comment: @PaulKnopf: There was one book I read years ago on COM and/or ATL, I remember it was by MS Press, Inside COM or something (memories fade out over years). I remember it was helpful and easy to understand though. You might want to check these references out: [Good Intro to COM Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129276/good-intro-to-com-programming/130512#130512).